# Как сделать запус программы в windows от имени администратора?

Tags: c++, windows

Пишу программу на С++ и мне надо что бы она выполнялась от имени администратора. Что бы на любом пк при открытии появлялось окно UAC с уведомление о том что нужно выполнить от имени администратора. Как можно это реализовать ?[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/bb756929(v=msdn.10)?redirectedfrom=MSDN

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Как указано в коментарии, создать манифест с соотвествующим `requestedExecutionLevel`, см https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/bb756929(v=msdn.10)?redirectedfrom=MSDN

В текущих Visual Studio не обязательно создавать файл вручную, и проделывать все шаги по ссылке. Опции компилятора:

- [`/MANIFEST:EMBED`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/reference/manifest-create-side-by-side-assembly-manifest?view=msvc-160) генерирует манифест и встраивает его в ресурсы исполнимого файла
- [`/MANIFESTUAC:'requireAdministrator'`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/reference/manifestuac-embeds-uac-information-in-manifest?view=msvc-160) включает соотвествующий узел в манифест

Через IDE - *Configuration Properties > Linker > Manifest File > UAC Execution Level > requireAdministrator (/level='requireAdministrator')*:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

---

Для не подписанных исполнимых файлов окно будет несколько отличаться (фон не синий, насколько я помню), и не будет включать название издателя.