# Как убрать повторную работу программы после нажатия "да" при запросе администратора

Tags: c++

Проблема такая:
После запуска программа запрашивает права администора.
Если нажать "Нет", то просто закроется
Если нажать "Да", то программа становится будто батником, консоли просто открываются и закрываются постоянно и не дают ничего сделать

Как исправить?

Вот код:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <windows.h>
#include <shellapi.h>

int main()
{
    SHELLEXECUTEINFO info = { 0 };
    info.cbSize = sizeof(info);
    info.lpVerb = TEXT("runas");
    info.lpFile = TEXT("ConsoleApplication1.exe");
    info.nShow = SW_NORMAL;

    if (ShellExecuteEx(&info))
    {
        std::cout << "Программа успешно запущена с правами администратора." << std::endl;
    }

    else
    {
        DWORD error = GetLastError();
        if (error == ERROR_CANCELLED)
        {
            std::cout << "Пользователь отменил запрос на получение прав администратора." << std::endl;
        }
        else
        {
            std::cout << "Не удалось получить права администратора. Ошибка: " << error << std::endl;
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: ¿и что делает это `ConsoleApplication1.exe`?

Comment: Возможно это глупо, но это и есть код той ConsoleApplication1.exe. Знаю, что из-за того что это из-за этого и произходит, но вот как исправить это не знаю. Мне просто нужно чтобы вначале программа запрашивала права администратора, не знаю как подругому делать

Comment: Вам нужно чтобы программа именно запускала сама себя от имени администратора или просто сразу запускалась от имени администратора? Если второе, то гораздо проще использовать [манифест](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/1328002/3380).

Comment: Мне особо не важно, мне важно, чтобы у программа была запущена от имени администратора. Раз второй легче, можешь помочь как это сделать?

Comment: Так читайте ответ по ссылке.

Comment: А, всё, спасибо большое!

Comment: Только один нюанс: при отклонении запроса на права администратора вы не сможете вывести никакие сообщения, программа просто сразу закроется. Если же пользователь нажал да, то программа запустится от администратора.

Comment: Ну, мне и не нужно чтобы она работала без прав администратора, так что это не важно

Comment: Так если программа запускает сама себя рекурсивно без остановки, то вы это и видите. Добавьте аргумент какой-нибудь, чтобы второй процесс не начинал создавать третий, а сделал что-то еще.

Comment: А напишите кто-нибудь ответ, который реализует именно задумку автора, без манифеста. Вопрос-то хороший.